# How to insert a data from one table to another using spring data JPA?

Tags: sql, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

How to insert a data from one table to another using spring data JPA.
I have query like like this

```
Insert into stack_tbl ( name , app_timestamp) 
Select b.areaname as name, SYSTIMESTAMP as app_timestamp 
From stack_main b
left join stack_tbl c
on c.name = b.areaname
where b.areaname IS NOT Null
AND c.name IS NULL
AND b.open = 'Yes'
GROUP BY b.areaname
ORDER BY b.areaname ASC
```

How can use spring data JPA to write this query in effective way.
I am very much new in spring data JPA. Is there way we can do so.
Thankyou if someone can guide me in write the JPA code for this

Comment: You have to use a native query

Comment: How to do that like write this native query can you give an example please